# Retrieving child from firebase with no tag

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a child node from firebase that has no tag/name. I know this isnt the correct way to store child nodes in firebase, its just the only way I can store them for a count function to work.

I am trying to retrieve the category which would be 'Technology' or 'Biology and Ecology' among others.My database is set up as follows:

```
  CountLikes{
    Project 23{
      Biological and Ecological{
          Votes: 1
                }}

    Project 32{  
      Biological and Ecological{ 
           Votes: 0
              }}

     Project 439{
      Technology{ 
          Votes: 2
               }}
```

I am able to retrieve the project name (ie. "Project 23", "Project 32") and the number of votes using the following:

```
 //Button Click Listener
    mReadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CountLikes/");

            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       String name = ds.getKey();
                       Long vote = ds.child("Votes").getValue(Long.class);


                       mProjectName.setText(name);
                       mProjectCategory.setText(String.valueOf(vote));
                    }
               }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
           ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Is there anyway I could retrieve the category?

Comment: If `vote` shows the correct result, then `name` should be the level above it (`Biological and Ecological` or `Technology`). If that isn't the case, can you show the actual JSON from the database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sorry yes you're right! I guess what I need help retrieving is the 'Project 23', 'Project 32' rather than the name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your data structure is unclear to me, making it hard to understand exactly what you're looking for. But this code will traverse the entire `DataSnapshot` with the listener that you current have:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CountLikes");

ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(child.getKey()); // prints "Project 23", "Project 32", etc
      for(DataSnapshot grandchild: child.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println(grandchild.getKey()); // prints "Biological and Ecological", etc
        System.out.println(grandchild.child("Votes").getValue(Long.class)); // prints 1, 0, etc
      }

    }

 }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
});
```